# OpenFileDialog does not return on Open after selecting Desktop under Favorites

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am using the OpenFileDialog to specify where to create a file and getting different if I click Desktop under Favorites vs Desktop under This PC.
- click Desktop under Favorites and Open then takes the dialog to This PC and stays open (undesirable behavior)
- click Desktop under This PC and Open returns with the file path set to C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyFile.request (desired behavior)

How can I get Favorites Desktop to behave the same as This PC Desktop?

Here is the OpenFileDialog constructor:

```
        var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            AddExtension = true,
            CheckFileExists = false,
            CheckPathExists = true,
            DefaultExt = "*.request",
            InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
            FileName = "MyFile.Request",
            Multiselect = false,
            RestoreDirectory = true,
            Title = "Select location for request file"
        };
```

I am running on Windows 8.1

Comment: Wrong class, use SaveFileDialog.  Click its Save button after you selected the directory.

Comment: @HansPassant - that was it. Thanks!